# In Canopy it seems I cant write in the BDName.sqlite sitting in the same location as run-file

Tags: sqlite, filepath, canopy

In Canopy v2.1.1 ( Python 3.5.2)  it seems I cant write in the DataBaseName.sqlite sitting in the same location as run-file?!

I am testing for file and file is FOUND fine:

```
> if (os.path.isfile(db_loc_1)):
```

But cant execute Query

```
> db.execute (sql_query_str)
```

I get

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table

Thanks. 
-PL

Comment: It seems in a way this thread answered my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126276/7613463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in a way this thread answered my issue...

Yes, and the code described there is good practice for a working program.

However if you are just playing around at the command line, an easier solution is to change the working directory to match where you are running the script. This is done from the drop-down menu at the upper right of Canopy's Python panel. See: 
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/2.1/quick-start/code_editor.html#change-directory

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment Jonathan, this would be a very hand feature going fwd.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "would be a very handy feature". This *is* a feature and it answers your question as far as I understand it.

Comment: You got  it @Jonathan